# TFS Iteration Capacity By User

Tags: tfs, capacity-planning

In my company, the development team is often working on several iterations of the same software at once.

For instance, over the next 2 weeks:

Bill is working on a feature for Interation 1 for a week, and will then move onto a Iteration 2 feature for a week.

Fred is working on Iteration 1 for the entire 2 weeks.

Now, if I set the daily hours (7.5) for Bill and Fred for Iteration 1, it assumes that both of them are working exclusively on Iteration 1, and so gives me 140 hours, In fact I only have 105.

How can I tell TFS that Bill is only working on Iteration 1 for a week?

Answer (score 0):

In the capacity view for the sprint use the "Days Off" for Bill to set which days he's not available on.

Comment: I would be a lot nicer if there was an interface available that would allow be to set the days that somebody IS available for a sprint rather than when they are not...

Comment: @JohnH Of course, if they did that, then people would be complaining they want the opposite :-)